Metric identfier cannot be interpreted - scikeras.wrappers.KerasRegressor
I am trying to tune hyperparameters with scikeras.wrappers.KerasRegressor and I am getting the problem described below:
Code:
    # define a func to create an instance of lstm_model
def create_lstm_model():
    
    model = Sequential([
            LSTM(5, input_shape = (Xtrain.shape[1], Xtrain.shape[2]), dropout = 0.1, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True),
            LSTM(10, dropout = 0.05, activation = 'tanh'),
            Dense(5, activation = 'relu'),
            Dense(1)
        ])
    model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics = [keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])
    
    return model

#create the sklearn model for the network
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn = create_lstm_model, verbose = 1)

#param grid
batches = [16, 32]
epochs = [3, 4]

param_grid = dict(batch_size = batches, epochs = epochs)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model,
                    param_grid = param_grid,
                    cv = 3)
grid.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, validation_data = (Xvalidation, yvalidation))

Error:
    fn_or_cls = keras_metric_get(metric)
  File "/home/aaa/Desktop/aaa/aaa/2024-gold-price-prediction-with-lstm-model/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/metrics/__init__.py", line 204, in get
    raise ValueError(f"Could not interpret metric identifier: {identifier}")
ValueError: Could not interpret metric identifier: loss

I started with much more complex code and simplify it to minimum during the trouble shooting. I was even trying to remove metrics from the model func.
Do you have any suggestion what's wrong with my code?

Since you are using different libraries to achieve two different tasks, the error may be due to a mismatch in the Keras backend version in both libraries; I would suggest using the name of the loss as a string.
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics = ['mean_squared_error'])


Unfortunately, I got the same error as above. Any other suggestions? In the worst case scenario, I will manage it with for loops.

change loss also to string

I changed loss to loss = 'mean_squared_error' and optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error' as well.
For both cases I got the same error as above.
